# how to get the count of product review in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1

I want the count of product reviews from collection for login customer.
based on either customer id or product id.

Comment: Please check my answer & let me know if it's working or not.

Comment: hi,Fatal error: Call to undefined method Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Collection::getEntitySummary()

Comment: when i am trying to execute its throwing an exception

Answer (score 3):

There is already defined function in **Review ResourceModel**. Check `vendor/magento/module-review/Block/view.php` line 139

Inject the model

```
public function __construct(
                        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
                        \Magento\Review\Model\ReviewFactory $reviewFactory
) {
        $this->_reviewFactory = $reviewFactory;

}
```

Call the predefined function  **getTotalReviews**

```
public function getTotalReview()
        {       
            $proId=10;
            return $this->_reviewFactory->create()->getTotalReviews(
                    $proId,
                    false,
                    $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
                );
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have count using `$this->getReviewsCollection()->getSize()` or you can directly use `getCollectionSize()`.

you can find reference from core module `module-review`

`/vendor/magento/module-review/Block/Product/Review.php`

```
/**
     * Get size of reviews collection
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getCollectionSize()
    {
        $collection = $this->_reviewsColFactory->create()->addStoreFilter(
            $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
        )->addStatusFilter(
            \Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED
        )->addEntityFilter(
            'product',
            $this->getProductId()
        );

        return $collection->getSize();
    }
```

Comment: hi Ronak,i have 2 products with reviews but i am not able to get that count as 2 still i am getting count as zero only.

Comment: Can you pls post your code?

Comment: thanks, this is the answer if you want show count of reviews which already approved by admin

Comment: @mrfizh you'r welcome, If this works for you then please upvote the answer so everyone can use the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**In block file :**

pass product collection in parameter

```
public function getRatingSummary($product)
{
    $reviewCount = $product->getRatingSummary()->getReviewsCount();
    return $reviewCount;
}
```

You can call this function in phtml file for **reviewcount**.

Comment: what is use of this code `$this->_reviewFactory->create()->getEntitySummary($product, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());`

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function __construct(


   \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session,


   \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Product\CollectionFactory 


    $collectionFactory,


         \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager


   )


public function getReviewCollection()
    {


         $customerId = $this->_session->getCustomer()->getId();


         $this->_collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()


                         ->addStoreFilter($this->_storeManager->getStore() ->getId())


                            ->addCustomerFilter($customerId)


                            ->setDateOrder();


         return $this->_collection->getSize();
    }
```